# Why is this URL Rewrite not passing URL string?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I am trying to redirect

```
http://www.indiegamers.co.uk/post?id=1
```

to

```
http://www.indiegamers.co.uk/post/1
```

This is the .htaccess file I am using, but it is not passing the URL string

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond ^/post/([^/]+) /post?id=$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Options +Indexes  -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^post/(.*)/? post.php?id=$1   [L]
```

Try this